Comparing message text to gettext function result in Aiogram message handler
In my Aiogram router code I have several handlers that check the user's text against the buttons text translated by gettext module:
@router.message(F.text == gettext("Settings"))
async def view_settings(message: Message):
    ...

In the beginning of the code I set up the gettext function default value:
import gettext as gt
gettext = gt.translation("ru", "translations", languages=["ru"]).gettext

which returns the function for translating buttons text into Russian.
Every handler works fine until user set up their language to another language like English or Spanish:
gettext = gt.translation("en", "translations", languages=["en"]).gettext

The user's language is not Russian anymore but the handlers still compare user's text to buttons text that was translated into the first initiated language, the Russian.
Is there any way to recalculate gettext function value in the handlers every time when Aiogram dispatcher decides a handler to call? I'll say in advance, don't suggest switching to inline-buttons.
P.S. I would be glad to make a single @router.message(F.text) handler where I would check the text alternately via if-else, but because I need to use a FSM in the handlers arguments, this option is not suitable.
The full code that has the issue (some unimportant things were removed to boost the readability):
import gettext as gt
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder

gettext = gt.translation("ru", "translations", languages=["ru"]).gettext

router = Router()


@router.message(F.text == "English")
async def change_to_english_language(message: Message):
    global gettext
    gettext = gt.translation("en", "translations", languages=["en"]).gettext
    await message.answer(gettext("Now your language is English"))


@router.message(F.text == gettext("Settings"))
async def view_settings(message: Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.button(text=gettext("Language"))
    builder.button(text=gettext("Preferred name"))
    await message.answer(gettext("What do you want to set up?"),
                         reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))


I have solved my issue, there's a way to use lambda functions after all:
@router.message(F.text, F.func(lambda msg: msg.text == gettext("Settings")))
async def view_settings(message: Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.button(text=gettext("Language"))
    builder.button(text=gettext("Preferred name"))
    await message.answer(gettext("What do you want to set up?"),
                         reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))


Solution:
Remove the gettext Function: Instead of defining the gettext function globally, define it locally inside each handler function.
Store Language Setting in Message Object: Store the user's language setting as a property of the Message object. For example, you can use a structure like message.bot.get("user_language").
Check Language in Every Handler: At the beginning of each handler function, check message.bot.get("user_language") to determine the user language and create the appropriate gettext function.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
import gettext as gt
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder

router = Router()

@router.message(F.text == "English")
async def change_to_english_language(message: Message):
    await message.bot.set("user_language", "en")  # Dil ayarını kaydet
    await message.answer("Now your language is English")

@router.message(F.text == "Русский")  # Rusça dil seçeneği eklendi
async def change_to_russian_language(message: Message):
    await message.bot.set("user_language", "ru")
    await message.answer("Теперь ваш язык русский")

@router.message()  # Varsayılan işleyici
async def handle_message(message: Message):
    user_language = await message.bot.get("user_language", "ru")  # Varsayılan dil Rusça
    gettext = gt.translation(user_language, "translations", languages=[user_language]).gettext

    if gettext("Settings") == message.text:
        builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
        builder.button(text=gettext("Language"))
        builder.button(text=gettext("Preferred name"))
        await message.answer(gettext("What do you want to set up?"),
                             reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))
    else:
        # Diğer mesajlar için uygun işlemleri yapın
        pass

Description:
Each handler function now uses the correct gettext function according to the user language.
Language change messages ("English" and "Русский") update the user language.
The default handler uses the Russian default language if the user language is not set.

I don't need ChatGPT answers, it didn't help me anyway

immoral personn .
